# Can't enable proprietary nVidia driver on debian 8 with bumblebee

Tags: nvidia, x-server, proprietary-drivers, bumblebee

I am running the Debian 8.0 64bit (Jessie, the stable release) on my HP laptop.
I am having hard time in installing the proprietary nVidia driver of my graphic card

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GF108M [GeForce GT 630M] [10de:0de9] (rev ff)
```

I have followed step by step the guides on debian wiki.
Bumblebee is required since my graphic card comes with nvidia optimus.
So far so good, I think I have all the right packages required on my machine.
Now I have to enable bumblebee.
It turns out the right command is

```
sudo optirun nvidia-settings -c :8
```

So a graphic front-end appears, I leave all the defaul checks and I have just to save the configuration file in the /etc/X11 folder as xorg.conf.
But at the system restart I get the black screen and x can't start, it says that there are "No screens found".
Here it is the log

```
[    74.012] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
[    74.014] (--) PCI:*(0:0:2:0) 8086:0126:103c:181d rev 9, Mem @ 0xd4000000/4194304, 0xc0000000/268435456, I/O @ 0x000050$
[    74.014] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[    74.015] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[    74.017] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    74.017]    compiled for 1.16.4, module version = 1.0.0
[    74.017]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 8.0
[    74.017] (==) AIGLX enabled
[    74.017] (II) LoadModule: "nvidia"
[    74.017] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module nvidia
[    74.017] (II) UnloadModule: "nvidia"
[    74.017] (II) Unloading nvidia
[    74.018] (EE) Failed to load module "nvidia" (module does not exist, 0)
[    74.018] (EE) No drivers available.
[    74.018] (EE)
Fatal server error:
[    74.018] (EE) no screens found(EE)
[    74.018] (EE)
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support
         at ....
 for help.
[    74.018] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/home/zarathushtra/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.0.log" for additional infor$
[    74.018] (EE)
```

Answer (score 1):

## Just use Bumblebee

I too was misguided by the 'You don't seem to be using the nvidia driver' message the nvidia settings GUI gave me, so I tried to run `nvidia-xconfig`. **Don't run the nvidia-xconfig tool** or it will leave you with no X server at next reboot.

Hopefully you can step back by removing `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`

Because this is what happened to me: I thought the installation of Bumblebee wasn't complete, and I needed to enable the nvidia driver. And then, as I rebooted, I stumbled upon the exact same error you had: X server crashed, because no screens were found.

It seems this is because optimus technology prevents direct display rendering (from the [Bumblebee FAQ](https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/wiki/FAQ#how-it-works)).

So you've actually found the answer yourself, and it's bumblebee.

***You don't need to do anything with the nvidia-driver. Bumblebee will automatically pull it in for you, and use it when you need it. All you need to do is call `optirun` with the program you need to launch on the graphics card.***

Everything else is handled by the CPU, and that's for the best because bumblebee turns off the graphics card when it's not used, meaning energy savings combined with on-demand performances, and that's the point of the optimus technology.

All credit goes to [allicoder](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/117495/allicoder) for his research on his [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/267978/136989)