# No desktop after nvidia driver installation

Tags: debian, xorg, nvidia

I run Debian 8 Jessie on my Sony Vaio Laptop. It has an **Nvidia Geforce GT 640M LE** graphics chip.

I followed the official Debian Wiki article to install `nvidia-drivers` instead of nouveau:

https://wiki.debian.org/NvidiaGraphicsDrivers

Now I am running **Nvidia Driver 352.79** which should be compatible to my GPU according to the mentioned wiki pages.
After the installation I ran nvidia-xconfig which created an `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` for me automatically:

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Unknown"
    HorizSync       28.0 - 33.0
    VertRefresh     43.0 - 72.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

The problem is when I boot up, I do not get to see the desktop environment - here is the complete `Xorg.0.log`:

```
[    21.803]
X.Org X Server 1.16.4
Release Date: 2014-12-20
[    21.803] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[    21.803] Build Operating System: Linux 3.16.0-4-amd64 x86_64 Debian
[    21.803] Current Operating System: Linux sony-jessie 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt20-1+deb8u4 (2016-02-29) x86_64
[    21.803] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-4-amd64 root=UUID=743ceb34-b848-49b3-8a7e-b5c86d2abf7c ro quiet
[    21.803] Build Date: 11 February 2015  12:32:02AM
[    21.803] xorg-server 2:1.16.4-1 (http://www.debian.org/support)
[    21.803] Current version of pixman: 0.32.6
[    21.803]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
        to make sure that you have the latest version.
[    21.803] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
        (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
        (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[    21.804] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Fri Mar 11 19:08:24 2016
[    21.804] (==) Using config file: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf"
[    21.804] (==) Using config directory: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[    21.804] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[    21.804] (==) ServerLayout "Layout0"
[    21.804] (**) |-->Screen "Screen0" (0)
[    21.804] (**) |   |-->Monitor "Monitor0"
[    21.805] (**) |   |-->Device "Device0"
[    21.805] (**) |-->Input Device "Keyboard0"
[    21.805] (**) |-->Input Device "Mouse0"
[    21.805] (==) Automatically adding devices
[    21.805] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[    21.805] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[    21.805] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[    21.805]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    21.805] (==) FontPath set to:
        /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
        /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/:unscaled,
        /usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/:unscaled,
        /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
        /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi,
        /usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi,
        built-ins
[    21.805] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[    21.805] (WW) Hotplugging is on, devices using drivers 'kbd', 'mouse' or 'vmmouse' will be disabled.
[    21.805] (WW) Disabling Keyboard0
[    21.805] (WW) Disabling Mouse0
[    21.805] (II) Loader magic: 0x7f0af2e3cd80
[    21.805] (II) Module ABI versions:
[    21.805]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[    21.805]    X.Org Video Driver: 18.0
[    21.805]    X.Org XInput driver : 21.0
[    21.805]    X.Org Server Extension : 8.0
[    21.806] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
[    21.806] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card1)
[    21.808] (--) PCI:*(0:0:2:0) 8086:0166:104d:909c rev 9, Mem @ 0xb9000000/4194304, 0xc0000000/268435456, I/O @ 0x00007000/64
[    21.808] (--) PCI: (0:1:0:0) 10de:0fd3:104d:909c rev 161, Mem @ 0xb8000000/16777216, 0xa0000000/268435456, 0xb0000000/33554432, I/O @ 0x00006000/128
[    21.809] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[    21.809] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/linux/libglx.so
[    21.821] (II) Module glx: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[    21.821]    compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
[    21.821]    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
[    21.821] (II) NVIDIA GLX Module  352.79  Wed Jan 13 15:54:44 PST 2016
[    21.821] (II) LoadModule: "nvidia"
[    21.821] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/nvidia_drv.so
[    21.822] (II) Module nvidia: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[    21.822]    compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
[    21.822]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    21.822] (II) NVIDIA dlloader X Driver  352.79  Wed Jan 13 15:31:15 PST 2016
[    21.822] (II) NVIDIA Unified Driver for all Supported NVIDIA GPUs
[    21.822] (++) using VT number 7

[    21.822] (EE) No devices detected.
[    21.822] (EE)
Fatal server error:
[    21.822] (EE) no screens found(EE)
[    21.822] (EE)
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support
         at http://wiki.x.org
 for help.
[    21.822] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
[    21.822] (EE)
```

Especially the following lines should be of use. Unfortunately not for me, I could not find anything useful about it:

```
[    21.822] (EE) No devices detected.
[    21.822] (EE)
Fatal server error:
[    21.822] (EE) no screens found(EE)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Forget about the nvidia-driver

**All you need for a GeForce card is Bumblebee.**

See [allicoder](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/117495/allicoder)'s [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/267978/136989) as well as [mine](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/305571/136989) on the subject.

Also be sure to checkout the [Bumblebee FAQ](https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/wiki/FAQ).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/155732)

Comment: @grochmal:  I'm actually not so sure, although the answer is of doubtful quality.

Comment: I'm sorry I just stumbled upon this question after I had already answered the other one and got lazy.
I am aware that I need reputation to comment, and I tried my best to provide an actual _answer_ but the problem is nobody seems to have gotten the nvidia-driver to work in such a setup, and bumblebee does provide a way to use the graphics card, which is - I assume - the intent of the writer.